# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')¿Por qué no me muestra el uid del usuario en la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-auth, uuid

¿Por qué no me muestra el usuario `uid` en la pantalla? Tengo una autenticación de base de fuego simple con correo electrónico en una aplicación React Native. Todo funciona a la perfección, el inicio de sesión y el registro. El usuario inicia sesión sin problemas en Firebase. Pero cuando quiero que me muestre el `UID` del usuario y agrego este fragmento de código, me muestra el error y la aplicación se rompe:

```
<Text> Welcome  {user.uid} </Text>
```

He visto otros ejemplos de compañeros en los que sí funciona, usando el mismo código, pero no entiendo el mío porque no me funciona

He buscado soluciones en Internet sin éxito. He visto problemas similares, otras preguntas similares a las mías en este sitio, pero no iguales, ya que como digo, este código funciona para otras personas, pero no para mí. si borro el fragmento "{user.uid}"todo funciona perfectamente

Error mostrado por la consola:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

***This error is located at:
    in HomeScreen (at SceneView.tsx:126)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:118)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:210)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:280)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:278)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in CardSheet (at Card.tsx:557)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:242)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:295)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:536)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:14)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:530)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:242)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:295)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:526)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at Card.tsx:520)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:218)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:649)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:242)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:295)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at src/index.native.tsx:171)
    in Screen (at Screens.tsx:37)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:642)
    in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:238)
    in ScreenContainer (at Screens.tsx:20)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:561)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at Background.tsx:13)
    in Background (at CardStack.tsx:559)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:437)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:46)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:430)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:429)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:118)
    in Unknown (at createStackNavigator.tsx:117)
    in StackNavigator (at AppStack.js:9)
    in AppStack (at Routes.js:28)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at Routes.js:27)
    in Routes (at navigation/index.js:9)
    in AuthProvider (at navigation/index.js:8)
    in Providers (at App.js:5)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in pinkilinkyApp(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:600***
```

Aquí está mi código:

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native"
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'

import FormButton from "../components/FormButton"
import { AuthContext } from "../navigation/AuthProvider"
import globalStyles from "../styles/global"

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext)
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.containerHome}>
      <Text style={globalStyles.textHome}>Welcome  {user.uid} </Text>
      <FormButton buttonTitle="Logout" onPress={() => logout()} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

---

Routes.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
    
import { AuthContext } from './AuthProvider'
import AuthStack from './AuthStack'
import AppStack from './AppStack'

const Routes = () => {

  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState()

  const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    setUser(user)
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged)
    return subscriber // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, [])

  if (initializing) return null// podemos usar un cargador mientras carga firebase

  return ( 
    <NavigationContainer>
      { user ? <AppStack/> : <AuthStack/> }
    </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
  
export default Routes
```

---

**index.js**

```
import React from "react"

import { AuthProvider } from './AuthProvider'
import Routes from "./Routes"

const Providers = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Routes />
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}

export default Providers
```

---

AuthProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        login: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        register: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        logout: async () => {
          try {
            await auth().signOut();
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider
```

Comment: El error te está diciendo que `user` es null. No está siendo obtenido del Context, por algún motivo

Comment: Pues no entiendo que pasa, el usuario esta registrado en Firebase.

Comment: En qué parte renderizas el componente `AuthProvider` de AuthProvider.js? No lo veo en el código que mostraste

Comment: Se envia en el `index.js` de navigation, envuelve a `Routes`. Añadió este archivo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por lo que veo, el `useState` que usas para conseguir las credenciales de `auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)` es distinto al del contexto `AuthContext` que es el que usas para conseguir los datos en el home. Permitiendo finalmente que si se renderize `<AppStack/>` pero con el valor de `user` en el contexto como `null` .

Intenta cambiar el Routes.js de manera:

```javascript
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
    
import { AuthContext } from './AuthProvider'
import AuthStack from './AuthStack'
import AppStack from './AppStack'

const Routes = () => {

  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true)
  // Conseguir desde el contexto
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext)

  const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    setUser(user)
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged)
    return subscriber // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, [])

  if (initializing) return null// podemos usar un cargador mientras carga firebase

  return ( 
    <NavigationContainer>
      { user ? <AppStack/> : <AuthStack/> }
    </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
  
export default Routes
```

Aunque fuera esto igual me parece raro que a otros les funcione el mismo código con las mismas credenciales. Ahí debe haber otro problema que no creo pueda resolver con el código que muestras.

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar esto?

```
<Text style={globalStyles.textHome}>Welcome  {user !== null && user.uid} </Text>
```

Comment: Muestra error, no reconoce user.uid : `null is not an objet. (evaluating 'user.uid')`

Comment: Pero el usuario esta registrado, y existe. Si pongo lo siguiente, no me da error pero no muestra el `uid` del usuario, que es lo que necesito sacar a la pantalla: `{user ? user.uid : "Loading..."}` De esta manera me dice: `Welcome Loadin...`

Comment: si pones un console.log de user verás lo que estará pasando, si te sale Loading es por que le llega null

Comment: Pues ya no se que hacer, por que en Firebase si que esta registrado el usuario

Comment: A parte de registrar al usuario en Firebase, ¿lo almacenas en algún lado tú? Porque en tu Provider, veo que le pasas el usuario, el login, el registro y el logout, pero no veo en ningún lado que cambies el valur de `user` de nulo al valor de la función.

Comment: La verdad es se almacena en ningún sitio, y el `console.log(user)`en Home, sale `null`

Answer (score 1):

Según Firebase, este es el método correcto de almacenar el usuario:

```
const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password) // Tú acabas aquí, pero ellos meten un
// then donde reciben los credenciales del usuario y lo almacenan en user, como deberías hacer tú
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

Comment: Gracias por su esfuerzo @SergioGarciaDominguez, sigue mostrando el error: `null is not an object (evaluating 'user.uid')` He probado en dispositivos y emuladores, android e iOS, pero no hay forma. No se que estoy haciendo mal para que esto no funcione. Parado mi proyecto hasta que no encuentre solución

Answer (score -1):

El problema es porque user inicia en null al declarar el estado

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null) // El estado está en null
```

Y al hacer la petición se tarda en responder; pueden pasar dos cosas:
1.- Que la petición no esté respondiendo con los usuarios
2.- Que la petición tarde y al intentar leer el objeto user, como está en null aparece ese mensaje
Prueba esto

```
<Text style={globalStyles.textHome}>Welcome  {user?.uid}</Text>
```

Y luego has un console.log(user)
Y verifica que esté llegando como lo esperas.